# Como hacer consulta solr filter en opencms con Release date futuras

Tags: xml, programación-bajo-nivel, configuración, cms

Estoy trabajando sobre opencms 10.5, he agregado un list que llama todos los eventos sin problema, ahora quiero mostrar solo los eventos futuros desde hoy hasta 10 meses utilizando la opción "Availability->Release / expiration date->Release date" en el evento (event), he utilizado el filtro &fq=released:[NOW TO NOW+10MONTH] en el list, el inconveniente ahora es que como la fecha de publicación no ha llegado este evento solo se muestra en el modo edición y no en producción,

¿alguien me puede colaborar con alguna idea u otra opción para lograr mostrar estos eventos?

Answer (score 0):

Deberias tener un campo Fecha en el contenido y hacer el filtro de los contenidos a mostrar sobre ese campo, por ejemplo:

1. Campo en el contenido `(.xsd)` = `FechaEvento`
2. searchsettings `(.xsd)` añadir

```html
<searchsetting element="FechaEvento" searchcontent="false">
     <solrfield targetfield="FechaEventoDate" sourcefield="*_dt"/>
    </searchsetting>
```

3. El filtro (en español) sería `&fq=FechaEventoDate_es_dt:[NOW TO NOW+10MONTH]`

Los campos Lanzamiento (Availability) y Expiracion (Expiration) no te recomiendo que los uses para eso.